# How do you say "thumbs up" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

In many places online, things can be rated based on how many *thumbs up* or *thumbs down* it receives.

How is this expressed in Esperanto?

Similarly, the common movie critic expression: *I give it two thumbs up.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great question. This is my best answer.

Certainly one thing to keep in mind is that hand gestures do not always translate across cultures. Of course, when the little "thumbs up" is staring you in the face, you've got to call it something. I have been going with ***dikfingro supren*** having heard similar expressions in English, German, and French.

As a verb, you could go with ***klaketu sur la altan dikfingron*** or similar.

For the movie review expression, I would try a less literal translation like *mi plene aprobas* or *mi forte rekomendas la filmon*.

Comment: When I said this was by "best answer" - I kind of meant I wished I had a better one. I do think it's a workable answer. After reading some of the other answers, I wanted to comment that I considered a work play with "polekso" and rejected it for various reasons. In the meanwhile I also noticed that on Telegram the thumbs up is transcribed as "+1" which suggests - especially for YouTube - the idea of making the thumbs up gesture while saying something else like *donu al mi "plus unu"* or *se vi sxatas tion, klaketu sur 'plus unu'.*

Answer (score 0):

To nod is *kapjesi* which has the advantage of indicating the meaning of the gesture, this is good since bidding for yes isn't universal. The analogous excursion for thumbs up would presumably be *dikfingrobono*?

Comment: …aŭ *dikfingrojesi*?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to point out that there is a synonym for *dikfingro* – *[polekso](http://vortaro.net/#polekso)*. IMHO, the latter word sounds a bit better (and the compound *dikfingro* is not *that* transparent – I presume someone with *dikaj fingroj* has 10 *dikfingrojn* :-P  .) So, maybe we could also use *poleks-jesi*, *poleks-nei*, and maybe even ”polekson!” and ”malpolekson!” for slangy ”thumbs up!” and ”thumbs down!”?

Comment: *Polekso* is much less common than *dikfingro*, so when using it, you risk not being understood. Someone with thick fingers still only has 2 *dikfingrojn*, but 10 *dikajn fingrojn*. Joining an adjective and a noun into a single word always expresses a different meaning than keeping them separate.

Comment: Bjørn - Actually "dikfingro" vs "dika fingro" is a classic example used in explaining Esperanto word formation.

Comment: @MarcosCramer : Okay, so ”belknabino” would have a different meaning than ”bela knabino; ”bonparolo” than ”bona parolo”? I can somehow see it, but are you sure the meaning *always* changes? Is it because the adjective is re-interpreted as a noun when suffixed? :-)

Comment: @TomasoAlexander : Thank you, I had no idea that these words were often used as examples. :-) Interesting.